# Bootstrap 5 Show Modal Code Behind (Asp.net C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, bootstrap-5

I tried everything but I couldn't success it.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModal() {
        var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('KullaniciAramaSonuc'), {});
        myModal.show();
    }
</script>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="KullaniciAramaSonuc" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Şifre İşlemleri</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Kapat"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <asp:Label ID="lblMesaj" CssClass="h5" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I call the method codebehind nothing happens. But when I try it with bootstrap 4.3 it works. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you check your bootstrap css/script sequence. It should be in this form: 
1.) CSS file (doesn't matter what sequence it is in CSS)
2.) Bootstrap JS script (This should be first)
3.) Popper JS and other JS if included. (And then all other js scripts afterwards)

Comment: When i triger it button like this;
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>'

it work. There is no problem with js and css

Comment: You can check this link: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Open-Show-Bootstrap-Modal-Popup-Window-from-Server-Side-Code-Behind-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I used masterpage and I found solution for bootstap5 modal , like this:

1-change function like this:

```
function openModalAddSchool() 
{ 
    var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModalAddSchool'), { keyboard: false }); 
    myModal.show(); 
}
```

2- take bootstrap.js and poper uppersite . after css

Comment: Please make use of `code blocks` when pasting sample code in answers.